# Why is my div being pushed out of its container div?

Tags: html, css

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4kuz0/7S8cu/). (may need to scroll right on the output to see my missing element).

There seems to be an issue which makes my `logout` div be pushed out of its container div before. I've had this kind of issue happen before and I'm not sure what causes it. I have tried removing each element `header` `title` and the `<ul>`, but it seems that it keeps being pushed out of what its contained in.

What's going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: Check my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7S8cu/4/). I had changed something in your css.

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt THank you but could you please tell me what you have changed? There's a fair bit of CSS there.

Answer (score 2):

The logout div escapes its container div because it's floated right, and float takes an element out of the normal document flow. You can force the parent to contain it by adding `overflow:auto`

http://jsfiddle.net/7S8cu/2/

This kind of layout is generally often handled by using grids nowadays, such as Bootstrap or Foundation grids, which take care of the basic layout code for you.

Comment: Thank you, I can see that the fiddle works, but I can't see where you've added `overflow:auto`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to `object ul`

`ul li` are block elementes and its take 100% width by default. So u need to set width and float to the elememt

```
.objects ul{ 
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    diplay:inline-block;
    float:left;

}
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7S8cu/3/)